# Psychopy error on installation - overflowerror line number table is too long

Tags: psychopy

I am trying to install psychopy on linux mint from the default repositories (i.e. ubuntu jammy).

Installation fails with this error:

```
OverflowError: line number table is too long
```

Has anyone else encountered this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only occurs when using Python 3.10 I believe and it's fixed in the current development branch of PsychoPy's github repository. You can see the required changes in the following pull request, but also note that the recommended version of Python to install PsychoPy is 3.8 not 3.10. I think there are going to be other points of pain using Python 3.10

https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/pull/5185

Comment: Thanks Jon. I did try the fixes suggested in that thread but they only replaced one error with another. I'll try with Python 3.8 then. Thanks for the tip!